# "unable to read repository" for "all" Red Hat add ons into Eclipse 2020-06

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I have gotten Eclipse 2020-06 installed under Windows 10 and have also gotten it to recognize and "update" my Project from Eclipse Oxygen.

I need to install Red Hat Tools and neither it nor installation of other Red Hat add ons is working. Everything fails with "unable to read repository".

For example, I have tried to install using both the Eclipse Marketplace and Help Install New Software for:

JBoss Tools, Code Ready Studio and I get:

```
Unable to read repository at https://devstudio.redhat.com/12/stable/composite/12.16.0/compositeContent.xml
Unable to read repository at https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/oxygen/updates/content.xml
Unable to read repository at https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/updates/content.xml
Unable to read repository at https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/2020-06/updates/content.xml
Connection to http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/staging/updates/central/4.16.0.Final/p2.index failed on Received fatal alert: internal_error. Retry attempt 0 started
```

All of the attemps show the following in the Errors log :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
```

When I am using Install New Software I get the above error as soon as I selet the (Red Hat related) Work With item.

I can reach the internet with the Eclipse "embedded" browser. In Install New Software I can select non-Red Hat packages and see all of the available modules. I have deleted the cache at p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache and I have Removed and added back the Source for Red Hat Tools (as above).

My searches have resulted in numerous older posts with suggestions that a proxy is causing the problem but I don't see how that can be the case. This is failing on a home network with no proxy and the Windows 10 system Eclipse is running on does not have a proxy set up.

Can someone suggest why this is failing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you new install or did you upgrade to Eclipse 2020-06? If you upgraded, please show your `eclipse.ini`. Which Java exactly do you use to run Eclipse?

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using ?

Comment: Thanks to howlger & Jeff. This was a new install into a new Win 10 machine. I had previously installed OpenJDK 11.0.8.

Comment: Can you open [`https://devstudio.redhat.com/12/stable/composite/12.16.0/`](https://devstudio.redhat.com/12/stable/composite/12.16.0/) in a web browser on this machine? If yes, your Java installation seems to be broken (did you installed OpenJDK 11.0.8 via the [`.msi` from here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot)?). Otherwise, it might be a missing SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to howlger! I had a bad install of the JDK. I started fresh, installed AdoptOpenJDK's .msi, installed Eclipse and am finally able to install CodeReady Studio (includes Jboss Tools).  Thanks again very much!

Comment: This helped me too, installing JBoss Tools in Eclipse 2020-09.
Now I do wonder what is the difference between https://adoptopenjdk.net/ and Oracle OpenJDK (https://jdk.java.net/). 
When using Oracle OpenJDK and manually installing SSL certicate to https://download.jboss.org, installation seemed to fail on the files referenced by a non-SLL URL like the last one in the orginal post. With AdoptOpenJDK these errors do not occur and manual installation of the SLL certificate is not required.